# Name and first name are sorted differently for same person

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (columns: Person and Phone) with multiple rows for each person.
The problem is that the name is like "First Name + Last Name" or "Last Name + First Name" or "First + Middle + Last Name" format for the same person.
My exact case is that I have a phone number linked to two or three persons that have the name types as I indicated above.
How can I set a flag for each row to tell for example (see pic below) that Andrew Chen is the same person as Chen Mathew Andrew and Maya Chen the same as Chen Maya.

Using:MS SQL Server 2017

Image below is a mockup made in excel, it does not represent the actual database (sensitive data).
[image]

Comment: I would suggest using separate columns for your name fields (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName). Or taking it one step further and having a Persons table with an ID that you use as a Foreign key in Phone.

Comment: As @dvo mentioned, make a new table with the names separated. If you already have the data and need to separate it. The easiest way would be to add all those names to a new table by hand from the old table.

Comment: your suggestion is very good if I start to design the database from scratch, but I already have these values and I need to work with them. I can split the name column into three first, middle, last name columns but then I would need to check them in other rows to see if they match up... BTW I have 10.000 rows, cannot do this manually :)

Comment: But _Dane Taylor_ and _Taylor Dane_ can most definitely be two different people. How do you know?

Comment: @abra because they have the same phone number

Comment: Yes, but in your image, Maya Chen and Andrew Chen have the same phone number. So are Maya Chen and Andrew Chen the same person?

Comment: What is the context of this question / What problem are you trying to solve? If you're using the phone number as a key (by using it to determine two records are the same person), then you can leave it at that in most cases instead of creating a new column.

Comment: What if Andrew Smith is the father of Andrew John Smith, and they share a phone?

Comment: Are you using an integer to store the phone number? How much effort would it take to go back and properly design your table schema? That is where I would start if I were you. Remember to use the correct data type for each column. Names should be nvarchar, phone numbers varchar, anything having to do with a date or time use datetime, or time, or date, anything dealing with numbers where a mathematical operation could be done should be (like money or quantity) should be decimal or int or bigint etc.

Comment: Once you implement a poorly designed schema you start running into numerous issues like this that are best solved by correcting the schema instead of trying to find "clever" work arounds to try to make it work.

Comment: @dvo and mypetlion: These are children and the phone is the parent's number. The children attend a course and I want to check if they attended the next or previous year of this course. I cannot find them if they don't have the same name so I tried to find the phone number but it is associated to 2 or 3 persons. So what I want to achieve is exactly what I wrote in the post, flag them accordingly.

Comment: @Igor - a get this data from a CRM app, I cannot design the database or edit it. I just get an extract in xls from this CRM app and import it into my SQL server

Comment: Why are there multiple records for the same person in this system and then with multiple name variations? Why not a single record?

Comment: Also I do not think it is going to be possible for you to do this with out any errors. Matching on name variations is difficult. Users might have added punctuation like a comma between names or used a middle initial or a full middle name or omitted it etc. Trying to find all matches is not going to be easy. You best bet would be to use some type of text index service like lucene and then create a match based on a percentage but even this is not going to be full proof.

Comment: There is an expression when it comes to dealing with data dumps like this: [Garbage In, Garbage Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

Comment: You never mention this but what is that first column in your screen shot? Is that from the system and does that already tell you which records should be grouped together? If so why are you not using that?

Comment: @igor your are right about the trashy data, but for now this is what I`ve been provided with and I have to do a good job (of course with errors). The picture is made by me in excel, it does not represent a screenshot from the database (sensitive data). In the next month I will ask the CRM manager to change the database design but for now this is what I've got...

Comment: How would you know that Maya and Andrew are one person? They could be a couple sharing the same phone.  Not everyone uses a mobile, even in these days.

Comment: Maybe if you do a `pivot` based on the phone number, you might get what you want.  Not perfect, but not terrible.  OR really, it just sounds like you're considering all "people" with the same phone number to be the same person . . .

Comment: i think something like Levenshtein distance would work here.. anyone with expertise?